# Bind Datatable data to Gridview in Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto

I search all over the stackoverflow and unable to find a suitable answer for my problem.
I wanted to bind datatable values to datagridview in windows form.Specially data table in one class and Gridview in Seperate file.

Here is my Code.

```
namespace MyProj
{
  public partial class ThisAddIn
{
  public string GetDetails()
    {
      // Some Codes here
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id");
        dt.Columns.Add("uid");
        dt.Columns.Add("email");

        //Some codes here.I just only give a data table part only.

         DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

           row["id"] = sid;
           sid++;

           row["uid"] = uid;
           row["email"] = e;
           dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
}
```

I Just tried to add Gridview,here is that code.
First i add Add -> NewItem -> WindowsForm & add as form1.cs

Then i add Gridview to this form1.cs class from toolbox.Then double click gridview.

Here is my form1.cs coding

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //ThisAddIn th = new ThisAddIn();
        this.dataGridView1.Visible = true;
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.DataSource =dt; // here show dt does not contain the current context.
```

}

Both files are under same namespace.When i tries to create a object from a class (ThisAddIn th = new ThisAddIn();)then it shows,

> > ThisAddIn.ThisAddIn(Microsoft.Office.tools.Outlook Factory factory,IsServiceProvider serviceProvider)
> >
> > This AddIn does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

I'm a fresher to c# and please help me to solve this problem,If you can give me a solution with explanation is great..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) The GetDetails method must return a DataTable, so I changed `string` to `DataTable` and return `dt;`

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
public DataTable GetDetails()
  {
  // Some Codes here
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("id");
    dt.Columns.Add("uid");
    dt.Columns.Add("email");
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();    
     row["id"] = sid;
     sid++;    
     row["uid"] = uid;
     row["email"] = e;
     dt.Rows.Add(row);
     return dt;
  }
}
```

2) Notice how I instantiate the ThisAddIn class, then I call the GetDetails method - returning the results into a DataTable who's scope is in context.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    ThisAddIn th = new ThisAddIn();
    //Declare a DataTable and call to GetDetails
    DataTable dt =  th.GetDetails();
    this.dataGridView1.Visible = true;
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

3) When you instantiate `ThisAddIn th = new ThisAddIn();` you get the error:

> This AddIn does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

To resolve this you need to supply some values (arguments in the parameter) when instantiating the class:

```
ThisAddIn th = new ThisAddIn(value1, value2, etc)
```

Comment: Which values do i need to provide? can i provide dt here because now dt returning ?

Comment: In Visual Studio when you type the opening bracket `(` a tool tip will appear telling you what values it expects. You can also open your class `public partial class ThisAddIn` and it should have a constructor method called `public ThisAddIn(Type value, Type value)`

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void BindProductsGrid()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = bl.BindProducts();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dt.Rows[i]["Product_id"].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dt.Rows[i]["Product_name"].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dt.Rows[i]["Quantity"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```